# Check condition on nested loop add to list, java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Below I have two lists. While looping the two lists, I need to check a condition add to one element.

```
List<EcStgClientRolesRecipients> ecStgRoleList = new ArrayList<>();

for (EcStgClientRolesRecipients ecStgClientRolesRecipients : ecStgClientRolesRecipientList) {
    for (EcStgClientRoles ecStgClientRole : ecStgClientRoleList) {
        if (ecStgClientRole.getRoleId().equals(ecStgClientRolesRecipients.getRoleId())) {                        
            ecStgClientRolesRecipients.setEcStgClientRoles(ecStgClientRole);
            ecStgRoleList.add(ecStgClientRolesRecipients);
        }
     }
     break;
}

return ecStgRoleList;
```

I am tried to convert into Java 8 code, it is not working. What am I missing?

```
List<EcStgClientRolesRecipients> filtedRoleRecipients = new ArrayList<>();  

Predicate<EcStgClientRolesRecipients> roleRecipientCheck =
    recipient -> ecStgClientRoleList.stream()
        .anyMatch(ecStgClientRole ->  recipient.getRoleId() == ecStgClientRole.getRoleId());

filtedRoleRecipients = ecStgClientRolesRecipientList.stream()
              .filter(roleRecipientCheck)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i was try to covert in java 8 , but it is not working??

Comment: i can not put java 8 tag, i am not having reputation 1500

Comment: _but it is not working..._ you r repeating an unclear statement

Comment: `recipient.getRoleId().equals(ecStgClientRole.getRoleId())`?

Comment: That also tried

Comment: if you don't tag me with `@` there's no way I know you added a comment btw

Comment: sry, about the that @Eugene, i was in hurry , issue in UAT

Answer (score 2):

I can think of this for example, but it's hardly any more readable than a simple for loop:

```
ecStgClientRolesRecipientList.stream()
            .map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                    ecStgClientRoleList.stream().filter(y -> x.getRoleId().equals(y.getRoleId())).findAny(), x))
            .filter(pair -> pair.getKey().isPresent())
            .map(pair -> {
                EcStgClientRolesRecipients e = pair.getValue();
                e.setEcStgClientRoles(pair.getKey().get());
                return e;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```